# Nine-patch StateListDrawable rendering issue

Tags: android, android-layout

After updating to **SDK tools revision 15** from revision 12, my EditTexts and Buttons all appear distorted like so...

[image: How it looks now]   [image: How it used to look]

Now **is this a bug with the revision?** Because when I preview what the layout looks like with the "Graphical Layout" tab it appears normal. But as soon as it is compiled and put on my phone or the emulator, it is distorted.

Here is the StateListDrawable xml for the buttons. Each drawable referenced in this is a **9patch**. The EditTexts are done in the same fashion.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_grey_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_grey_pressed" android:state_focused="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_grey_pressed" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_grey_default"></item>
</selector>
```

Comment: There must be a glitch in the matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue I've had too when I updated to SDK 14.

I found a solution in `Window>Preferences>Android>Build` by setting "Build output" on `Normal` and then `Project>Clean>Clean All`.

Comment: Simply cleaning it didn't do the job for me either. But the "Build output" step did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've copied and pasted from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20725#c10) and it worked:

> 1. Disable auto-refresh, build automatically.
> 2. Full clean all projects.
> 3. Build all projects.
> 4. Clean the main project.
> 5. Build the main project.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping those nine-patch drawables (I suppose `@drawable/button_grey_pressed` refers to `/drawable/button_grey_pressed.9.png`) into xml nine-patch drawables:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nine-patch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/button_grey_pressed"
    android:dither="true" />
```

You will have to give this xml file the name which will be different from that of `button_grey_pressed.9.png`, let's say `button_grey_pressed9.xml`